# Grouping Messages by subjects from MySQL via query or php

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am currently working on a personal message module for a Symfony 3 based management system. Doctrine 2 is used as a DBAL.

For displaying the messages I want to group them by a subject (and because a message only has one sender and one recipient, by the persons).
I am struggeling with the best way the get the messages from the MySQL DB (via Doctrine) and the sorting/grouping.

The first thought was to get a distinct list of subjects (for a specific person) by a database  request. Then making a new request for every subject. I guess this could be faster than gathering all messages of this person (sender or receiver) and sort/group them with PHP functions. On the other hand that could mean a huge number of db requests, which could slow down the whole application.

Messages are db represented entities. Another way could be to relate every message to a persisted conversation. So at least I don't have to make the query for the subjects though I still have to query for every conversation.

Generally this application is used only by about 30 people. So performance isn't really a thing at the moment. But I want to code that in a suitable way, which could be also applied to a bigger user base.

I hope you could give me some input about the ways to handle this problem.

best regards,
spigandromeda

Comment: This is far too broad. Sit down with any basic book or tutorial.

Comment: @Strawberry thank you so much!
I dont think it's like asking how to define a variable in php ... so a little more precise hint where to look up would be nice.

Comment: In general, you want as few round trips to the database as possible. In general, this means understanding how JOINs work.

Comment: Ok. We might talking about cross-purposes.
I already know how to query such things. That's no problem. 
The question issues the performance. Three ways and I have to less experience to determine which would be the best or if there is a best one.

Comment: "Then making a new request for every subject." Sorry, but can you see that with the knowledge you profess, it would be illogical to make this statement?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can get you don't want to code niether slack nor facebook out of your application, but want to add some layer of the scalability to already existing module in case when number of your system users will grow. Thats why I can suggest that lazy loading will be easiest solution that you can apply. Just load only amount of messages that user can see on his screen by the query - it will guarantee same size of query no matter how your messages table will grow. Than javascript and additional queries(which should load exactly same batch of the entities) via ajax will come in hand to load/render new messages. You can easily find more info on applying lazy loading via google. And don't forget, that you could add various data attributes(like data-notification, data-announcement and others) on the html containers by which messages are represented. They could be used to make sorting/grouping of the messages on the user's machine via javascript without any additional load of your server resources. Hope that helped with your question!